# ld: b/bl/blx thumb2 branch out of range from

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I'm trying to build an iOS application and I'm hitting an error in debug mode.

```
ld: b/bl/blx thumb2 branch out of range (17330692 max is +/-16MB): from xxxx (0x0204CC28) to zzzz (0x030D4010) in 'yyyy' from libMyLib.a(MyObject.o) for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This only happens for an iOS debug build. iOS-Simulator is fine in both modes.

I came across "[This page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pdfnet-sdk/b4EoBiH_zjc/J-9oLJgdPPUJ)".

Which suggests this issue is known to Apple `(rdar://16186742)`. But the workaround does me little good. i.e.

```
The work around is to rearrange the source files in the project build phases and/or libraries in the Link Binary with Libraries section. With a few re-arrangements this problem should go away.
```

I spent way too much time re-arranging the library link order. That moved the problem between different `*.a` files but did not fix it.

Is there any proper solution for this issue?

"xcode 5.0.1" installed.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in **Xcode 5.1.1**. So installing a recent version might be the easiest fix.

Comment: I'm getting this in Xcode 6.1.1 (no solution yet): ld: b/bl/blx thumb2 branch out of range (20117852 max is +/-16MB): from _setButton.island (0x0000C570) to _setButton.island.2 (0x0133BED0) in '_setButton.island' for architecture armv7

Comment: I've seen this occur occur in XCode 6, & 6.1. It is still a problem.

Comment: I've seen this occur in XCode 6.1 also ;(

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, but the difference is my project works fine with `XCode 5.0`.

After I update `xcode` to `5.1.1`, the problem `thumb2 branch out of range` occurs.

My project has a lot of `CPP` static libraries to link to. These static libraries are build with the compiler option `-mthumb`.  By default `xcode` should use the option `-mthumb` for device.

My workaround is use the comiler option `-mno-thumb` when build the debug version of these static libraries.

I think application become slower and bigger is acceptable in debug mode. In release mode, it will work fine.